# Express.js server-side events implementation - events not emitted

Tags: node.js, express

I have basic Express app implemented as follows;

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
require('./routes')(app);
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000.'));
```

App route implemented in this fashion;

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express';
module.exports = function(app: any) {
    app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.send('Application is running.');
    });
    require('./api/api-events')(app);
}
```

I can create event records via the POST method, however I'm unable to allow event stream to consume and emit them to clients. Important part of the server-side events implementation is as follows:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

module.exports = function(app: any) {

    let eventStreamRecord: Array<Object> = [];

    function eventsHandler(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        res.flushHeaders();
        if (eventStreamRecord && eventStreamRecord.length) {
            const data = "data: " + JSON.stringify(eventStreamRecord) + "\n\n";
            res.write(data);
        }
        next();
    }

    /*
        Perform server-side event streaming.
    */
    app.get('/events', eventsHandler);

    /*
        Creates an event with provided name.
    */
    app.post('/entity', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        const reqBody = req.body;
        if (reqBody && reqBody.name) {
            let eventDao: EventsDao = new EventsDao();
            const result: OperationResultSet = eventDao.createEvent(reqBody.name);
            console.log('api - post req - created event record: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            if (result && result.data) {
                const payload = { "type": "Created", "entity": {"name": reqBody.name, "id": result.data.id} };
                eventStreamRecord.push(payload);
                res.json(payload);
            } else if (result && result.errorMsg) {
                res.status(400).send(result.errorMsg);
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).send('Bad request. Event name is missing!');
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `GET /events` not returning anything ? You must use `res.end()` after you are done with `res.write()` , so try replacing your `next()` with `res.end()`.  Also I'm not sure why you are using `next()` there.

Comment: I've removed `next()` and replaced it with `res.end()`
I then called curl as `curl -H "Accept: text/event-stream" http://127.0.0.1:3000/events`
However, it's blinking cursor, no data is received after the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I found it much easier to use the NPM package; [express-sse-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sse-ts)

It gets the job done easily.